# What happened to this 10 year old unopened plastic bottle?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, pressure

A colleague of mine found this unopened Aquarius bottle (non-carbonated drink) that was 10 years past its expiration date.

The bottle was collapsed inward which would suggest that the pressure in the bottle was lower then outside the bottle.

Can someone explain what happened here? Also, what happened to the air inside the bottle?

> [image: 10 year old bottle]
>   [image]

Comment: Not that I doubt you, but as a clarification: Are you sure some idiot didn't squeeze it like that and leave it lying around 10 years ago ;-)

Comment: As someone who has never had any of it: Is this drink carbonated?

Comment: Nope, that didn't happen.  We opened the bottle and it was still very firmly shut close.  This is not a carbonated drink.

Comment: Aha, I see! And by "*still very firmly shut close*", should I take it that bottle was *unopened* prior to finding it?

Comment: Yes, it was closed all these years

Comment: Thanks. I've edited your post, do give it a look to make sure I didn't distort anything :-)

Comment: Further clarification: Can you shed any light on where/how the bottle was stored all this time? i.e- was it in a refrigerator, icebox, etc? And could the  bottle have been taken out of storage in those 10 years?

Comment: The bottle was stored in a closet for 10 years, it was never taken out

Comment: Okay, and the temperatures normally lie in what range? 25-27 degrees Celsius (normal room temp.) or something else?

Comment: Regular room temperature. Between 18°c in the winter and 25°c in the summer?

Comment: Added ingredients in Dutch/French

Comment: The real question is, where did all the liquid go?

Comment: After we opened it, the bottle expanded again.  The liquid seemed to be on the same level as when the bottle was bought.  Suggesting no liquid escaped/evaporated/was lost in the process :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the drink is not carbonated, no liquid has been escaping the bottle, and the components don't seem to be able to participate in any kind of chemical reactions involving gaseous products, I assume the gas that's been leaked is air.

I also cannot imagine any kind of chemical reaction involving consumption of this amount of air leading to such a severe bottle deformation. My theory is that air simply escaped over time through the bottleneck. There are 2 parts made of 2 materials with *different thermal expansion coefficients*:

- the bottle itself (polyethylene #1 (PET), or polyethylene terephthalate (PETE));
- the screw cap (polypropylene (PP)).

Due to the construction of the joint, both parts basically act as a pressure equalization valve. I suspect that the coefficients of thermal expansion are chosen in such a way that when heated, excess gas would slowly escape in order to minimize the risk of explosion when the storing conditions for the finished product is not met. So, when the bottle is heated, the air is slowly leaking out. Once the temperature drops, the "valve" closes and the process stops. Over the course of 10 years, there surely were many temperature fluctuations making air leave the bottle little-by-little.

Comment: If nothing can fix oxygen or perhaps CO2 from some fermentation, it must be something like that.

Comment: What do you think of forming CO2 which might selectively permeates out?

Comment: I guess if fermentation took place, it would be noticeable, but it looks like OP has no complaints regarding the color or smell. And there is no membrane that can selectively pass $\ce{CO2}$ through; the lid-bottle joint is hardly *that* selective:)

Comment: I agree.  But for selectivity I mean the bottle . I thought for some  reason it could be more permeable to CO2 than nitrogen and oxygen.

Comment: Oh. But how? PET is not quite porous, and if it were, then smaller diatomic gases (oxygen and nitrogen) should've escaped first, I think.

Comment: I didn't mention this in my OP but the color of this drink is more orange then shown on the picture. So the drink also lost its color in those 10+ years

Comment: I was just thinking of permeability because of 10 y is pretty long. Not high science but besides the fact that P lowered I find this rather puzzling. I do not see any trivial chemistry in it. I try to look for pet permeability to CO2 and air. And water too.

Comment: Assuming CO2 is formed at expense of O2 or anaerobic processes I found something on this direction http://www.composite-agency.com/archive/Carbon-Dioxide-Diffusion-PET.pdf

Comment: @Johan Interesting point. Perhaps that's simply the result of the drink's contents and coloring agents degrading (since it's well past the expiration date). andselisk's argument sounds pretty solid to me. If this answer helped you, consider clicking the "Accept answer" button (below the voting interface) :-)

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51695/why-do-sealed-plastic-bottles-of-pop-collapse-as-the-contents-get-old